# Get cell format information from Google Sheets using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I'm reading values from Google Sheets using `google-api-php-client` and `google-api-php-client-services` libraries this way:

```
   $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($this->calendarService->getClient());
        $spreadsheetId = 'abhslJcKXjIqS8bAJ1lojekXuOk0WOSrdtVtJ2C512jQ';

        $range = 'Sheet Name';

        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);

        $values = $response->getValues(); // returns all cells as array
```

How can I get information on format of each cell? (eg. number, date, email etc.).

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? I cannot understand the relationship between `information on format of each cell` and `number, date, email etc`. In order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and the sample output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 1):

None of the responses you can get from the Spradsheets.batchUpdate [1] includes information about the cells format. Neither the Spreadsheets.values.get request [2] includes this information in its response (ValueRange object [3]). You're able to change the cells format using UpdateCells request [4], but you can't retrieve it using Sheets API.

Using Apps Script there's a function which retrieves the number/date format [5], you could do a workaround with it.

[1] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/response#Response

[2] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

[3] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange

[4] https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getNumberFormat()

Answer (score 1):

You can get cell formatting also get textFormat (bold,strikethrough etc) Beside, you can search the object there are more specs related to each cell.

[Cell Documentation of google api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells)

To be able to get this you should use Google_Service_Sheets -> spreadsheets method by including gridData like below :

```
$sheets = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client); //callling sheet api with authorized client 
$spreadsheet = $sheets->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId,['includeGridData' => true]);
```

And i assume spreadsheet has 1 sheet to show you correct place of formatting :

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheets();
$format = $sheet[0]['data'][0]['rowData']['values'][0]['effectiveFormat']['numberFormat]; //this is one of example from that object
```

Hope it helps